# Custom order list of strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of strings that holds database column names and is in a random order with a random number of items. This list could look as follows:

```
List<string> searchBy = new List<string>(new string[] { "LAN_Share",        
"[Group]", "AccessMask", "[Server]",
"max([TimeStamp]) as [TimeStamp]" });
```

I also have made another list `fixedList` (shown below) that has the order I would like the `searchBy` list to be in. The problem is that I would NOT like to add the missing elements to the `searchBy` list, just order them.

```
List<string> fixedList = new List<string>(new string[] { "[Server]", 
"LAN_Name", "LAN_Share", "[Group]", "[User]", "ID", "AccessMask", 
"max([TimeStamp]) as [TimeStamp]" });
```

`fixedList` has all of possible strings and the correct order. Once I have the correct order I convert the list to an array:

```
string query = string.Join(",", searchBy.ToArray());
```

And query the SQL database with:

```
SQL_Query("SELECT " + query + " FROM LANReporter")
```

Where SQL_Query is a working function that querys the database. Is this possible?

Comment: Show the query itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want the `searchBy`-list to be ordered by the second list? Then this should work:

```
var orderColumns = searchBy.OrderBy(s =>
{
    int index = fixedList.IndexOf(s);
    return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index;
});
```

If the second list always contains all columns you can simplify to `searchBy.OrderBy(s => fixedList.IndexOf(s))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can order it by the index they occur in the fixed list:

```
searchBy = searchBy.OrderBy(s => fixedList.IndexOf(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
var sorted = fixedList.Where (x => searchBy.Contains (x)).ToList ();
```

From `fixed list` (which is already ordered), you get items that exists in `searchBy` list.

Of course `fixed list` must contain all possible column names.